Why is SSML contour tag not changing the hz of the audio
I got this SSML from w3.org. AVSpeechUtterance(ssmlRepresentation:) is not complying with the contour. It doesn't change the hz. It always plays at the same hz level. I'm using: Xcode 15.3, iPhone 8 device with iOS 16.7.5, Swift.
Here's the String value for ssmlRepresentation. SSML with contour tag:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<speak version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis
                 http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/synthesis.xsd"
       xml:lang="en-US">
  <prosody contour="(0%,90Hz) (40%,90Hz) (0%,90Hz)">
    good morning
  </prosody>
</speak>

My code:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    guard let localUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(ssmlRepresentation: self.speechSML)         else {
        print("SML did not work.")
        return
    }
    self.utterance = localUtterance
    self.utterance.voice = self.voiceNoelle
}

self.synthesizer.speak(self.utterance)


This link says the following about contour:

Contour represents changes in pitch. These changes are represented as an array of targets at specified time positions in the speech output.


The first value in each set of parameters specifies the location of
the pitch change as a percentage of the duration of the text. The
second value specifies the amount to raise or lower the pitch by using
a relative value or an enumeration value for pitch (see pitch).

In your code, the second parameter in each pair passed to contour is set to a constant absolute value of 90Hz and the first and last percentage values are the same:
<prosody contour="(0%,90Hz) (40%,90Hz) (0%,90Hz)">

So, it makes sense that the "hz" (as in "Hertz" - the measure of pitch) is not changing.
Let's say that you wanted to increase the pitch by 20Hz at the beginning of the text, and then increase it by another 10Hz 40% of the way through, and then at 80%, decrease the pitch by 10Hz.  The code would look like this:
<prosody contour="(0%,+20Hz) (40%,+10Hz) (80%,-10Hz)">

Note that the pitch values (in Hz) are relative (prefixed with a +/-), and the percentage values increase from left to right.

I put a bad example as code. I had actually tired changing the different values.
    func makeSSMLString(at0: Int, at10: Int, at40: Int) -> String {
        
              <prosody contour="(0%,+\(at0)%) (10%,+\(at10)%) (40%,+\(at40)%)">
                good morning
              </prosody>

        return ...
    }


When I print utterance.speechString, it doesn't show the SSML parts. It only shows the spoken part "good morning".

I just tried your sample prosody tag in your answer. Something else is going on. The words are not spoken. The sound is like every syllable is interrupted. I get a message in the Debug window saying "Unable to list voice folder" four times.

@daniel - Apologies for the delayed reply!  Did you intend to mark my answer correct?

Oh. I actually meant to award the other guy. Sorry. Is it reversible? I haven't even tried the only idea I have at this time, which is to set the postUtteranceDelay property to 0, after I have chained the AVSpeechUtterance objects together by calling AVSynthesizer speak instance method each time the previous utterance ends. Do you have anything more. @CherryRomandiaz - the other answer - thinks contour may not be supported with Apple Speech Synthesis for iOS. I haven't checked to be sure.

I don’t think it’s reversible. Just wanted to make sure that credit was given where it’s due – to the extent that’s possible within the constraints of the platform. Unfortunately,  I have nothing else to offer.

We can move forward.
